# jqGrid: customizing the delete message

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have setup in jqGrid a delete function call that uses the native features for checking if a row have been selected in the grid or not as in the following code sample:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
     { add: true, addtitle: 'Add record',
       edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit record',
       del: true, deltitle: 'Delete record',
       addfunc: addFulfilment, editfunc: editFulfilment
     },
     {}, // default settings for edit
     {}, // default settings for add
     {
         // define settings for Delete 
         mtype: "post",
         reloadAfterSubmit: false,
         onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, postdata) {
             rp_ge.url = '/Customer/Delete/' + postdata;
         }
     }, 
     {}, // search options
     {}
);
```

This works fine showing a confirm message before the delete method get called.

Is there a way to customize the delete message that appear on the popup window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `$.jgrid.del.msg` or redefine other parameters from the localization file like *grid.locale-en.js*:

```
del : {
    caption: "Delete",
    msg: "Delete selected record(s)?",
    bSubmit: "Delete",
    bCancel: "Cancel"
},
```

You can overwrite some parameters only for one grid using additional `prmDel` option of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) with the same name (`msg` for example). Inside of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) the default values `$.jgrid.del` will be combined with the current `prmDel` options.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to customize the popup dialog? I mean dimension, the fact that is resizable and so on?

Comment: @Lorenzo: If you need more customizations you can define additional CSS parameters of the classes used in the Delete dialog: `delmsg`, `formdata`. In the CSS you can make some changes only for ids like "delmodnav"+grid.id and so on. I recommend you examine the dialog with some developer tools in IE, FF or Chrome. Corresponding CSS definition based on the classes or ids should solve all your problems.

Comment: @Oleg : Sorry this is an old but wanted to know how can we change the caption and text of delete dialog in jqgrid (4.15.2)

Comment: @aman: Yes, one can specify all the settings too. There are some small difference because free jqGrid allows to specify *different `del` settings for different languages*. You can overwrite the settings for *some locale* or *for the grid*. For grid settings you can include `caption`, `msg` and so on in `formDeleting` option of jqGrid (see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rmo2370r/19/ from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48102515/315935)). To make global settings for en-US locale: changes properties of `$.jgrid.locales["en-US"].del` instead of `$.jgrid.del`.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks for the quick response.